Science fiction movie where a man is chased by his own clone and kills him by accident
This guy is being chased by his clone and it's trying to capture him. The end of the movie the guy ends up shooting himself in the mouth and it kills the clone by sheer luck.

Do you know what decade you might have seen this movie?

More importantly, were these empanadas spicy or plain?

The real problem here is we can't talk about it. It's the first and second rules after all.

@Nohbody - Can you elaborate on how the guy killed the clone by shooting himself in the mouth? And did the guy survive, or were they both killed?

Fight Club maybe?

Was the villain definitely a clone, instead of a doppelgänger or other type of replica?

Could the clone be his future self? (Looper)

Spanish film Los Cronocrimenes (Time Crimes) from 2007?  The protagonist keeps messing with time only to wind up enacting the same scenario he is attempting to stop.

TimeCrimes is a great movie, and well worth seeing — but I don't think it's a match for this question, as no versions of the protagonist get killed at any point.  I don't recall any gunplay, either, nor any facial injuries.
